# Android WebView hide div

Tags: android, webview

I want to partially view a webpage on webview android and remove some div element from the webpage. I have a webpage like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

i tried like but all i see on page is title "none" or page loaded but show only white background
Do anyone have any ideas?

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('header').style.display = 'none';")
```

it's my java,

```
    package com.example.client6.tetrapolis;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import org.htmlcleaner.HtmlCleaner;
import org.htmlcleaner.TagNode;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class lichkab extends Activity {

public class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
{
view.loadUrl(url);
return true;
}
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
view.loadUrl("javascript:var con = document.getElementById('header');" +"con.style.display = 'none'; ");
}
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_lichkab);
//
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
//
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//
mWebView.loadUrl("#");
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.lichkab, menu);
return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
WebView mWebView;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I've got the same issue, so I changed JavaScript to look like this:

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"header\").setAttribute(\"style\",\"display:none;\");");
```

Hope it helps.
Bye!

Comment: I get a load of `I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null", source: my_long_url_is_here (1)`

Comment: I've figured it out: right at `onPageFinished()` the html is encrypted. By using webView.postDelayed(new Runnable(javascript))` delay it for 1 sec and then the html will be available

Answer (score 1):

note:hide id with class different bellow my code it's work :

When use with id i've got the same issue :

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"header\").setAttribute(\"style\",\"display:none;\");");
```

When use with class i've got the same issue :

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0].style.display='none';");
```